# PHP cookies in a multi-server environment

Tags: php, cookies, load-balancing

I am experiencing difficulties retrieving a cookie in an environment where the URL is http//somesite.com and the request is sent through a load balancing application and farmed out to various servers.  I can set the cookie using setcookie in a PHP script as follows:
    setcookie("NameTest", $cookieText, time()+3600, "/"); 
and a cookie somesite.com is created however when I attempt to read the values back from that cookie on the running system I never find the created cookie.  I know there must be a way of doing this but haven’t found anything I can use.  Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this function?

This of course works perfectly on a single server without the load balancing routine

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are round-tripped client<->server on every request. If the cookie's not present on subsequent requests, you'll have to figure out why the client isn't sending it. If the load balancer is transparent to the end user, then it shouldn't matter which server is handling the request - the client would've send the cookie regardless. So if it's not being sent, then it's not being set properly in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, because externally the client sees same IP and domain address. But if you need to share SESSION info, you have to use something like memcached or mysql to share session data between  nodes.

Comment: That, or sticky sessions, so a user gets the same server each time.